# How do I move this batch choice description to a newline?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch script template that includes a choice in it, I want to have the question for what the end-user wants to do, and the choice description(s) below the question. Here is my template:

```
@ECHO OFF
Color __
TITLE %TITLE%
ECHO.
:choice
set /P c=Do you want to %CHOICE%? & ECHO.(%DESCRIPTION%)
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :choice_yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "C" goto :choice_cancel
goto :choice
:choice_cancel
echo %CHOICE% has been cancelled.
:choice_yes
:: Insert additional commands or code here.
pause
@ECHO OFF
```

As you can see in the script, I have already attempted `& ECHO.(%DESCRIPTION%)` among other methods that insert a new line. I believe there needs to be an additional `ECHO` before the actual choice question with the above method, but due to the structure of the code I don't know where to place it. What am I doing wrong? Is there perhaps a character that needs to be escaped due to syntax?

Comment: From a UX perspective it's confusing to have  the request for input appear *before* the information the user must consider when answering. Just an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the question *and the input cursor* to be above the description output, you'll need a way to move the cursor upwards. Batch scripts cannot do this alone (though PowerShell possibly could); you'd need a small external tool which uses the Windows Console APIs to move the cursor a few lines higher.

If you want *only the question* to be above the description, allowing the prompt to blink below everything, that's easy – just output the question using a separate command:

```
echo Do you want to %CHOICE%?
echo %DESCRIPTION%
set /p ANSWER=^>
echo You entered %ANSWER%.
```

---

Your original attempt doesn't work for a different reason.

The `set` and the `echo` are completely separate commands – it does not matter that you separate them with an `&` instead of a line break; they are still executed individually:

1. first the `set /p a=b` command is run, showing the prompt, then reading a single input line;
2. then, *after* input has been already read, `echo %description%` is run, showing your text.

So in other words, `echo` does not insert a new line *in the script*; it tells the script to *produce* a new line in its output, but that's not the same thing at all.

(In other scripting/programming languages, to insert a new line *in the script* you would use `\n` or just a literal line break, but Windows batch scripts again have no equivalent to that.)