# Insert a newline with set parameter choice prompt

Tags: windows, batch

I am working on a script that asks the user for a choice, that then directs the user to another choice that will use `set` to place a parameter based on what they input. The choice has a prompt followed by a description that is placed below. Here is my current code:

```
:compress
cls
echo.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Type the payload name here:
set /p compress="(Don't include extensions)"
set LF=^
echo 
echo.
```

I want the choice prompt on line four, the description on line five, and the input cursor below the description on line six. My current script places the cursor immediately after the description. How do I move the user-input marker to line six with my set parameter prompt?

Comment: It's a feature of `set /p` to keep the cursor on the same line, so echo your description and have an empty set /p prompt. Otherwise you can get absolute/relative cursor positioning with recent windows 10 versions with ansi escape sequences.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but does this do what you ask: `echo Type the payload name here: / echo (Don't include extensions) / set LF=^ / echo. / echo. / set /p compress=" "`

Comment: Yes, @Twisty Impersonator, your method also works. Apologies for the confusing question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've already [answered a month ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1296395/):

Commands in batch scripts are executed from top to bottom, and their output likewise goes from top to bottom. If you want to swap two lines of text, just *swap the commands* which output them.

You want two lines of text, followed by the input cursor?

1. Use `echo` to print the first line of text.
2. Use `echo` to print the 2nd line of text.
3. Use `set /p` to receive input.

Example:

```
echo Type the payload name here:
echo (Don't include extensions)
set /p compress=
```

Comment: I see, I thought the syntax may have been different because of the `set ` command. I tried your method from my previous question here, but made a mistake resulting in failure. Thank you again for the help.